# vis.js - How to resize nodes at runtime

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I would like to resize nodes of a vis.js network at runtime. My goal is to create a slidercontrol to expand all nodes (an labels) or collapse them.

First, I've tried to manipulate the Scaling values.

```
var options = {nodes: {scaling: {label: {max: 180 , maxVisible: 180}}}};
network.setOptions(options);
```

But there are no results.

My second idea was to manipulate the value of every single node.

```
function IncNodeSize(Increment) {
    var CurrentNodes = nodesDS.get();
    for (var i = 0; i < CurrentNodes.length; i++) {
        CurrentNodes[i].value = CurrentNodes[i].value + 100;
    }
  }        
nodesDS.update(CurrentNodes); 
}
```

But this didn't work either.

Has anyone an idea how to resize nodes at runtime?

Comment: With the help ob the Developer Community i solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the [help](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3524) of the Developer Community I have solved the issue.
At first I had to change the options and than I had to update the nodes (with no datachange)
This two things together changed the sizes.

Comment: Could you please describe the solution in more details here and then accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply wanted to resize a single node. I too tried the `DataSet.update()` method, but to no avail. What did work, however, was to simply set the new property directly on the node object and call `Network.setData()`. Here's an example:

```js
const nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: 'Node 1', shape: 'circle', margin: 20 },
  { id: 2, label: 'Node 2', shape: 'circle', margin: 20 },
]);

const edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 2 }
]);

const dta = { nodes: nodes, edges: edges };

const network = new vis.Network(
  document.getElementById('graph'),
  dta,
  { interaction: { zoomSpeed: 0.2 } }
);

setTimeout(function() {
  const node1 = nodes.get(1);
  node1.margin = 50;
  network.setData(dta);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

Notice that I make sure to have a reference to the object (the `dta` constant) that includes both the `nodes` DataSet and the `edges` DataSet, before I start manipulating the node. That way I can call `Network.setData()` using that `dta` object.